# What is the fastest way to install GCC on Wind River 3.02?

Tags: linux, software-installation, embedded, gcc

I  really do not want to just blindly install rpm after rpm of dependencies I think I might need...

I know that this version of Linux is based off of Fedora 11.

I am currently trying to install yum to pull down all of the required files / installers. However, when trying to install yum via a RPM I am missing several dependencies. I have begun the hunt for these dependencies but they are becoming more and more obscure. Before I start installing all of these crazy RPMs is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for all Linux distributions and beyond is that you have two options to install a program system-wide:

1. Use a *package manager* (like `yum`) that takes care of all the dependencies and future updates/deinstallation.
2. Install the program "by hand" and take care of all the dependencies yourself.

The second option is *not* recommended on normal systems, especially for large and potentially critical pieces of software like GCC.

The situation is a bit different with embedded systems, where disk space is much more important than up-to-date software. You don't often do updates on such systems and you don't have as much software installed as on a desktop computer. So a package manager *on an embedded system* is rarely used.

---

But a more important question is: **why do you want GCC** on such system? If you need to build a specific program from source, you should instead use a **[cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-compiling)** on your desktop computer and then copy the binaries over to your device.

Comment: Thus far I have used Ubuntu to compile all of the required software.  However, we have been informed that we have to build drivers for this specific version of Wind River (it's been modified for our specific project).  I was instructed to build the drivers *on* the target system.  Believe me I do *not* want to put GCC on here, but my hand has been forced.

Comment: A faster solution might be to use qemu to simulate the target platform on your PC. But if that is not possible/allowed, then I'd just compile GCC (an potential dependencies, there shouldn't really be *that* many) and place in a separated path - like `/opt/something` on the target.

Comment: You might also consider cross-compiling GCC alone for speed benefits when running on the target. The binaries you might get would probably be rather generic for a given arch.